Unable to access bbPress forum pages though the content still there
The issue possibly started on Sept 30 when the domain connected with the WordPress instance on AWS expired.
As the site went down because of domain expiry, I connected with another of my domains with the aim of moving hosting from AWS Lightsail to WP Engine.
It was only after migration to WP Engine that I noticed that forum pages (using the bbPress plugin) were not opening.
For instance this forum topic page: https://progannum.com/?topic=comparing-list-manipulation-in-wolfram-language-vs-python
So I checked the copy on AWS Lightsail as well and there too forum pages not opening. I can still access the content via edit mode. So the content is not lost, either on the WP Engine copy here (progannum.com) or well AWS Lightsail (digitalsplendid.xyz).
Someone suggested refreshing by clicking save on permalinks, which I did on progannum.com. After that getting a completely blank screen instead of the earlier 'This page doesn't seem to exist' as still visible on AWS Lightsail WordPress copy here: https://digitalsplendid.xyz/forums/topic/comparing-list-manipulation-in-wolfram-language-vs-python/.
UPDATE:
The WP Engine chat support helped me in this way:

Also provided this thread for reference: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/blank-topic-pages-on-bbpress-while-using-twenty-twenty-two-theme/
